# get last alphabetic value without using lists

Tags: c#, string, compare

I have some `string`s, and I would like to get the letter that is last in *alphabetic order*.
I know how to do it on a `List<string>` (*ordering* the list), but what I would like is such a function :

```
private string getLastValue(string a, string b)
{
   //????
}
```

`getLastValue("a","b")` may return `"b"`

`getLastValue("azerty","qwerty")` may return `"qwerty"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just *compare* strings with a help of [StringComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer?view=net-6.0), e.g.

```
private string getLastValue(string a, string b) =>
    StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(a, b) > 0 ? a : b;
```

Note, that you can *choose* the comparer required: `Ordinal`, `OrdinalIgnoreCase` etc.

Comment: can you say why you would use `> 0 ? a : b` please? I see there is possibility to replace it by `ToString()` (If I understood correctly microsoft documentation.

Comment: @Siegfried.V: `Compare(a, b)` returns some *positive* value if `a > b`, *zero* if `a == b` and *negative* value when `a < b`

Comment: In fact, ToString() here makes no sense, I am "playing" with compare now to understand better.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Linq;

var data = new string[] {"azerty","qwerty"};
Console.WriteLine(data.Max());
```

or

```
var a = "azerty";
var b = "qwerty";

var inv = StringComparer.InvariantCulture;
Console.WriteLine((inv.Compare(a, b) < 0 ? b : a));
```

Comment: no way to do it without lists?

Comment: @Siegfried.V: Please see the edit.